# Why are array assignments incompatible, even though their data types are?

Tags: java, pointers, casting, pass-by-reference

```
byte b =10;   
int a = b;   // Primitive data type widening
             // Works perfectly fine
```

the above code will give no error/warnings. But why is the same not applicable for the below mentioned code?

```
byte[] b = new byte[10];
int[] i1 = b;             //Cannot convert from byte[] to int[]
int[] i2 = new byte[10];  //Cannot convert from byte[] to int[]
```

my question is, since int can hold any and all byte values, why is this not the case with arrays?

they are both holding the addresses afterall. And this would be **upcasting** if this was possible for ref variables.

Comment: `int[] i1 = b;` - b is not copied into `i1`, `i1` will point to the same address `b` is pointing to. So, what will happen if you assign an integer to `i1[0]` (which refs `b` and is a byte array - not an *int* array)?

Comment: I'm sorry i did not follow, could you please elaborate ? @BackSlash

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The language spec defines subtyping between array types in [Sec 4.10.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.3):

> The following rules define the direct supertype relation among array
>   types:
>
> - If `S` and `T` are both reference types, then `S[] >1 T[] iff S >1 T`.
> - `Object >1 Object[]`
> - `Cloneable >1 Object[]`
> - `java.io.Serializable >1 Object[]`
> - If `P` is a primitive type, then:
>
>   - `Object >1 P[]`
>   - `Cloneable >1 P[]`
>   - `java.io.Serializable >1 P[]`

The final bullets ("If `P` is a primitive type...") show that the language does not define any relationship between arrays of differing primitive types. The only valid assignments are:

```
byte[] bs = new byte[10];

byte[] bs2 = bs;
Object obj = bs;
Cloneable cl = bs;
Serializable ser = bs;
```

This doesn't provide an answer as to *why* it is like this; you'd have to ask the language designers. However, simple examples like that shown by [Eran](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50734663/3788176) demonstrate why it would not be safe to do as OP proposes.

It should be noted that the first line - which permits an assignment like

```
Object[] obj = new String[10];
obj[0] = new Object();  // ArrayStoreException!
```

was a design error: that arrays are covariant makes them not type safe. This is one reason to strongly prefer generics to arrays, since generics are *invariant*, and so prevent such assignments.

Comment: Although Eran's answer is very good for an understanding, this answer is the _correct_ one.

Answer (score 8):

The array created by `new byte[10]` can contain 10 `byte` values. If you were able to assign it to a variable of type `int[]`, the compiler would assume (mistakenly) that your array of `byte`s can contain 10 `int` values.

Consider the following code, which is invalid:

```
byte[] b = new byte[10];
b[0] = 10000; // too large for byte
```

and the following code, which is valid:

```
int[] i2 = new int[10];
i2[0] = 10000;
```

If `int[] i2 = new byte[10];` was valid, the compiler would have allowed you to store an `int` in a variable of type `byte`.

Comment: Nice example, but it might prompt one to ask why it works with reference-typed arrays (e.g. `Object[] objs = new String[10];`).

Comment: Following up on the same explanation, why is the same not working in *Wrapper Classes*?
 `Byte b = new Byte[10];`
 `Integer i = b;`
They are compatible, Byte ***IS A RELATION*** with Integer, shouldn't dynamic dispatch allow this, just by first checking the parameters in the Byte class and then storing it into Integer class ref variable?

Comment: @AshishSharma did you mean to ask why `Byte[] byteArr = new Byte[10]; Integer[] integerArr = byteArr;` doesn't work?

Comment: No, i asked exactly what i meant to ask, but i was wondering the same logic you just gave applied to the wrapper classes too

Comment: @AshishSharma why would assigning an array of Bytes to an Integer variable work? An array is not a sub-class of Integer. And assigning an array of Byte to a Byte variable also makes no sense. That's why I assumed you had a typo in your comment.

Comment: "Byte IS A RELATION with Integer" There is no such relation between `Byte` and `Integer`. There isn't even a relation between `byte` and `int`; it is just that the language defines a conversion from `byte` to `int` (a widening conversion).

Comment: @404BrainNotFound: References (pointers to objects) are each the same "size", so if an array of one reference type is treated as an array of another reference type, the indexing will still be correct; the only thing that might be wrong is type compatibility when you put something into the array (and that's checked at runtime and may throw an `ArrayStoreException`). On the other hand, a `byte` is one byte and an `int` is 4 bytes, so if you treat an array of bytes as an array of ints, the indexing will not work.